# Detailsview Edit and Insert using Databind

Tags: data-binding, dataset, detailsview

I Have a Detailsview  and I use dataset as a datasource of Detailsview, I want to employ the Edit/Insert on detailsview using Dataset as datasource, it was easy if I use SqlDataSource but is not my option.

Thanks

heres the code:

```
sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("Select *From Category", con);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Category");


            DetailsV.DataSource = ds;
            DetailsV.DataBind();
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method:

```
System.Data.DataSet ds = ...;
DetailsView dv = ...;
dv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Got it sir but my question is How to Apply the Detailsview EDIT/DELETE/INSERT When the detailsview datasource come from DATASET and the detailsview Property's autogeneratecolumns = true, it's means the the data of detailsview is dynamically generated